# Why does the @abstractmethod decorator only affects subclasses derived using regular inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, pep, abc

PEP 3119 -- Introducing Abstract Base Classes states that:

> The @abstractmethod only affects subclasses derived using regular inheritance; "virtual subclasses" registered with the register() method are not affected.

I'm wondering why this is the case.

What is the purpose of abc.ABCMeta.register() then?

What is the advantage of registering subclasses rather than subclassing directly via inheritance?

[PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/)

Comment: `register` doesn't require modifying an existing class at all.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why is this the case? What purpose does `register()` serve if it doesn't modify existing class?